# How can I load a PHP file every 5 seconds with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want a php program to be executed every 5 seconds using JavaScript. How can I do that?

I tried using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(
        function (){
            $.load('update.php');
        },
        5000
    );
</script>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: you could use a non-blocking server such as nodejs, or implement your php websocket server

Comment: AJAX request on a 5 second timer. (Not saying it's a good idea)

Comment: Use setTitmeout() and ajax

Comment: better set up a crone job

Comment: you should make sure that jQuery is loaded at this time so start with $(function() { ... your set interval and other code... }); then it should work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using jQuery and `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('your/file.php', function(data) {
      //do something with the data
      alert('Load was performed.');
    });
}, 5000);
```

Or without jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
         }
      }
    request.open('GET', 'http://www.blahblah.com/yourfile.php', true);
    request.send();

}, 5000);
```

Comment: I have a feeling there's some "Downvote the competition" on SO going on, users downvoting other answers on posts they answered.

Comment: @Dabido: In that case, I didn't say anything :P Good sportsmanship :D

Answer (score 7):

Try using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) to perform a XHR call. ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [non jQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest))

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Ajax call...
}, 5000);
```

This will execute your code inside the function every 5 secs

Comment: He wants to execute PHP with JavaScript. Not JavaScript with JavaScript. However +1 for helping a help vampire

Comment: @ColeJohnson: The ___only___ way to execute php from JavaScript is to do a AJAX call, to request a php page.

Comment: @Cerbrus I am aware AJAX is the solution. I'm just pointing out that your code doesn't give any indication of Ajax